# Do armor piercing ammo cause less damage to non-armored targets, compared to their regular, non-armor piercing counterparts?

Tags: rage

How do armor piercing ammo like the [Feltrite AR Rounds](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Feltrite_AR_Rounds) or the [Authority AV2x Rounds](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Authority_AV2x_Rounds) affect non-armored targets?

Do they cause less damage on non-armored targets, compared to their non-armor piercing counterparts (ala [Fallout New Vegas ammo types](http://www.falloutwiki.com/.50_MG#.50_MG.2C_armor_piercing))? Or are they simply better versions of their non-armor piercing counterparts?

I'm asking because I am deciding if I should still use regular non-armor piercing ammo or not, depending on if armor-piercing ammo work better against non-armored targets.

[Posts in this RAGE forum thread in the Steam Forums have different opinions about this.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3004254)

Answer (score 1):

From reading the descriptions of each of the types of armor piercing ammunition in RAGE, it looks like using armor piercing ammo on a non-armored target will do less damage, as a portion of the damage the ammunition does is to pierce the targets armor.

As per the [ammunition page](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Ammunition) there are quite a few different ammunitions that have an armor piercing ability. Here is some reading;

> [Feltrite AR Rounds](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Feltrite_AR_Rounds): The structural strength provided by Feltrite allows higher penetration and **cause more damage to armored targets**.
>
> [Authoritiy AV2x Rounds](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Authority_AV2x_Rounds): ...being able to put down both the unarmored and armored enemies quickly. It is **much more useful against the heavily armored enemies** such as Gearheads and the Authority infantrymen.
>
> [Steel-tipped Bolts](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Steel-tipped_Bolts): The bolts deal considerable amount of damage to the enemies. This ammo is effective against all types of enemies, as even the strong and armored enemies such as the Authority troops or Gearheads...

My conclusion from this is that armor piercing ammunition is still useful against unarmored targets, but gains additional damage in the form of piercing armor against the tougher enemies that do have armor.

Comment: "*... a portion of the damage the [armor-piercing] ammunition does is to pierce the targets armor.*" Is there a statement from the Rage wiki that backs this up or are you speaking from experience? I would like to make sure because I am deciding if I should still buy regular non-armor piercing ammo or not, depending on if armor-piercing ammo work better against non-armored targets.

Comment: From experience... most of the armor piercing ammo just does more damage in general, regardless of the target you're shooting at, due to it being ammo from later on in the game. Take for example FatMomma ammo, which does 4x the damage of Fatboys, which do more damage than standard ammo, regardless of if the target is armored or not, while still providing armor piercing.